# Elegant way to add elements in collections in Kotlin

Tags: design-patterns, collections, kotlin

I have a repeating pattern in my code in `Kotlin` where I have to check if the items are not `null` and add them to a collection and then return it. I have found Kotlin function `listOfNotNull`, but I will not work if I want to add a collection to the collection (replace `addAll()`). Do you know a non-verbose way to add elements to collection?

Example of the code I want to simplify:

```
private fun getItems(): List<BaseItem> {
    val items = ArrayList<BaseItem>()

    componentA?.let { items.add(it) }

    componentB?.let {
        items.add(it)
    }

    additionalComponents?.let {
        items.addAll(it)
    }

    componentD?.let { items.addAll(it) }

    return items
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listOfNotNull` function:

```
val nonNullAdditionalComponents: List<BaseItem> = additionalComponents ?: listOf()
val items: List<BaseItem> = listOfNotNull(componentA, componentB, *nonNullAdditionalComponents.toTypedArray(), componentD)
```

In this case we use `spread operator *` if we want to pass array's contents to the function.

Comment: I cannot cast *nonNullAdditionalComponents.toTypedArray() to List<BaseItem>

Comment: what type of `additionalComponents` variable?

Comment: it is of type `List<BaseItem>`

Comment: it think it does not work with `TypedArray()` because this method requires a safe call and this breaks the purpose of having `listOfNotNull`

Comment: `nonNullAdditionalComponents` is always non Null. I added the type to my answer. It should work.

Comment: my fault, I did not look carefully at the first line! :-) Thanks for your advice!